# Set/Get X509 CertificatePolicies Extension when importing DER/PEM in Java

Tags: java, bouncycastle, x509

I have problem with getting and setting Certificate Policies extension in Java. I am using Bouncy Castle 1.57.

I am adding extension to certificate generator like this:

```
boolean isCritical = Extensions.certificatePolicies;
String cpValue = Extensions.certificatePoliciesValue;
cerGen.addExtension(Extension.certificatePolicies, isCritical, cpValue.getBytes());
```

And getting this extension like:

```
byte[] policyBytes = certificate.getExtensionValue(Extension.certificatePolicies.toString());
if (policyBytes != null) {
    Object policyObj = new ASN1InputStream(policyBytes).readObject();
    policyBytes = ((DEROctetString) policyObj).getOctets();
    String policyField = new String(policyBytes); // this is cpValue when set
}
```

This works fine when until I export certificate, but when I export it to DER or PEM type, when I try to import it I am getting error:

> java.io.IOException: Invalid encoding for CertificatePoliciesExtension.

Here's my source code of import:

```
 CertificateFactory fact = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
 FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
 X509Certificate cer = (X509Certificate) fact.generateCertificate(is);
```

Exception occurs on last line when I try to generate certificate.

Comment: What's in your `cpValue` variable?

Comment: @Hugo It's CPS URI field, i.e. cpValue="aaa.bbb".

Comment: OK, I'll make some tests. What's your BouncyCastle version?

Comment: @Hugo I am using bcprov-jdk15on-157.jar and bcpkix-jdk15on-1.57.jar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error occurs because you are creating the extension as a single `String`.

Your code to get the extension works because you are reading it as a single `String` as well (you are reading exactly the same way you created it, that's why it works).

But the **Certificate Policies** extension has a well pre-defined format, and the `CertificateFactory` tries to parse the certificate according to this format.

In [RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#page-34) you can find the extension's format:

```
certificatePolicies ::= SEQUENCE SIZE (1..MAX) OF PolicyInformation

PolicyInformation ::= SEQUENCE {
    policyIdentifier   CertPolicyId,
    policyQualifiers   SEQUENCE SIZE (1..MAX) OF
                            PolicyQualifierInfo OPTIONAL }

CertPolicyId ::= OBJECT IDENTIFIER

PolicyQualifierInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
    policyQualifierId  PolicyQualifierId,
    qualifier          ANY DEFINED BY policyQualifierId }

-- policyQualifierIds for Internet policy qualifiers

id-qt          OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::=  { id-pkix 2 }
id-qt-cps      OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::=  { id-qt 1 }
id-qt-unotice  OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::=  { id-qt 2 }

PolicyQualifierId ::= OBJECT IDENTIFIER ( id-qt-cps | id-qt-unotice )
... and lots of other types definitions
```

Note that the extension is not a `String`. It's a sequence of `PolicyInformation`, which is a sequence of an identifier and qualifiers and so on.

I've created a sample extension with just one value, just as an example:

```
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.CertificatePolicies;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Extension;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.PolicyInformation;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.PolicyQualifierId;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.PolicyQualifierInfo;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.X509v3CertificateBuilder;

X509v3CertificateBuilder certGen = //create builder

boolean isCritical = true; // depends on your application (setting any value for tests)
PolicyQualifierInfo pqInfo = new PolicyQualifierInfo("aaa.bbb"); // the value you want
PolicyInformation policyInfo = new PolicyInformation(PolicyQualifierId.id_qt_cps, new DERSequence(pqInfo));
CertificatePolicies policies = new CertificatePolicies(policyInfo);
certGen.addExtension(Extension.certificatePolicies, isCritical, policies);
```

To read this extension, you can do:

```
import org.bouncycastle.x509.extension.X509ExtensionUtil;

X509Certificate certificate = // a java.security.cert.X509Certificate
byte[] policyBytes = certificate.getExtensionValue(Extension.certificatePolicies.toString());
if (policyBytes != null) {
    CertificatePolicies policies = CertificatePolicies.getInstance(X509ExtensionUtil.fromExtensionValue(policyBytes));
    PolicyInformation[] policyInformation = policies.getPolicyInformation();
    for (PolicyInformation pInfo : policyInformation) {
        ASN1Sequence policyQualifiers = (ASN1Sequence) pInfo.getPolicyQualifiers().getObjectAt(0);
        System.out.println(policyQualifiers.getObjectAt(1)); // aaa.bbb
    }
}
```

Creating the certificate this way, the `fact.generateCertificate` will create the certificate without error.

Comment: Great response! Thank you so much! I've succeeded.

Comment: Just to note that you should use `JcaX509ExtensionUtils.parseExtensionValue(policyBytes)` instead of `X509ExtensionUtil.fromExtensionValue(policyBytes)` nowadays.